# fail2ban regex matches, no bans

Tags: fail2ban

A few months ago, I setup fail2ban on a gentoo container running courier-mta.

```
# fail2ban-server --version
Fail2Ban v0.11.1
# courier --version
Courier 1.0.14 Copyright 1999-2018 Double Precision, Inc.
```

This same combination was running on a real machine with earlier versions of the software just fine. After some time, I realised that fail2ban wasn't banning anything. No firewall entries, no bans in the fail2ban log file.

After checking the config and going through the documentation, googleing, etc, I am stumped. The fail2ban-regex shows the jail is using the right filter/logpath, and finds plenty of matches:

```
# cat /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/courier-smtp.conf 
[courier-smtp]
enabled = true
filter = courier-smtp
action = iptables-allports[name=courier-smtp, protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/maillog
maxretry = 1
findtime = 60m
```

```
# fail2ban-regex /var/log/maillog /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/courier-smtp.conf 

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : courier-smtp, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use      datepattern : Default Detectors
Use         log file : /var/log/maillog
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 81805 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   2) [81805] ^msg="535 Authentication failed\.",cmd:( AUTH \S+)?( [0-9a-zA-Z\+/=]+)?(?: \S+)$
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [858343] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
`-

Lines: 858343 lines, 0 ignored, 81805 matched, 776538 missed
[processed in 46.84 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 776538 lines
```

The log (set to loglevel 5) shows f2b is processing log entries normally as far as I can tell:

```
2020-11-21 15:59:52,213 fail2ban.filter         [12241]: TRACE   Working on line 'Nov 21 15:59:52 mail courieresmtpd[13644]: error,relay=::ffff:45.142.120.38,port=41978,msg="535 Authentication failed.",cmd: AUTH LOGIN medic@com.au\n'
2020-11-21 15:59:52,213 fail2ban.datedetector   [12241]: HEAVY   try to match time for line: Nov 21 15:59:52 mail courieresmtpd[13644]: error,relay=::ffff:45.142.120.38,port=41978,msg="535 Authentication failed.",
2020-11-21 15:59:52,213 fail2ban.datedetector   [12241]: HEAVY     try to match last anchored template #00 ...
2020-11-21 15:59:52,214 fail2ban.datedetector   [12241]: #06-Lev.   matched last time template #00
2020-11-21 15:59:52,214 fail2ban.datedetector   [12241]: #06-Lev.   got time 1605938392.000000 for 'Nov 21 15:59:52' using template {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
2020-11-21 15:59:52,214 fail2ban.filter         [12241]: HEAVY   Looking for match of [('', 'Nov 21 15:59:52', ' mail courieresmtpd[13644]: error,relay=::ffff:45.142.120.38,port=41978,msg="535 Authentication failed.",cmd: AUTH LOGIN medic@com.au')]
2020-11-21 15:59:52,214 fail2ban.filter         [12241]: HEAVY     Looking for prefregex '^(?:\\[\\])?\\s*(?:<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>\\s+)?(?:\\S+\\s+)?(?:kernel:\\s?\\[ *\\d+\\.\\d+\\]:?\\s+)?(?:@vserver_\\S+\\s+)?(?:(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?\\S*(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?\\S*(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)\\s+)?(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\]\\s+)?error,relay=(?:\\[?(?:(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<ip4>(?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})|(?P<ip6>(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}::?|::){1,7}(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|(?<=:):)))\\]?|(?P<dns>[\\w\\-.^_]*\\w)),(?P<content>.+)$'
2020-11-21 15:59:52,214 fail2ban.filter         [12241]: TRACE     Pre-filter matched {'ip4': '45.142.120.38', 'ip6': None, 'dns': None, 'content': 'port=41978,msg="535 Authentication failed.",cmd: AUTH LOGIN medic@com.au'}
2020-11-21 15:59:52,214 fail2ban.filter         [12241]: HEAVY     Looking for failregex 0 - '^[^:]*: 550 User (<.*> )?unknown\\.?$'
2020-11-21 15:59:52,214 fail2ban.filter         [12241]: HEAVY     Looking for failregex 1 - '^msg="535 Authentication failed\\.",cmd:( AUTH \\S+)?( [0-9a-zA-Z\\+/=]+)?(?: \\S+)$'
2020-11-21 15:59:52,683 fail2ban.filterpyinotif [12241]: DEBUG   Event queue size: 16
```

I can't tell from this if the log entry triggers anything, but fail2ban-client shows no failures:

```
Status for the jail: courier-smtp
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed: 0
|  `- File list:    /var/log/maillog
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned: 0
   `- Banned IP list:
```

What else do I need to be looking at to see why there are no bans?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue all week. I assume you already tried it, and I certainly should have tried it way earlier. But, all I had to do was a reboot of the server and everything started working again. Never could figure out what caused the error, restarting services alone did not work.

Comment: Just tried it now out of desperation. No change.